# wordpress loop not showing data

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am trying to making a shortcode for wordpress the point is to be able to buy tickets for a theatre, I cant make it to retrieve the data from my wordpress posts, I  dont get anything back from the wordpress loop.

This code is located at the bottom of the functions.php in wordpress

The shortcode should be displayed in the homepage of http://iga.jpandroidpeter.com but as you can see there is no data displayed.

This is what I tried:

```
function teatro_func() {



        if (have_posts()):


                while (have_posts()) : the_post();
                    return 
                    ?>
                        <div class="teatro-all">

                            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>

                            <h2 class="teatro-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                            <h4 class="teatro-date" href="#">custom field date will go here</h4>
                            <h4 class="teatro-date" href="#">custom field price will go here</h4>
                            <h4 class="teatro-date" href="#">custom field place will go here</h4>
                            <a class="teatro-buy" href="#">BUY TICKET</a>
                            <a class="teatro-buy" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">READ MORE</a>



                        </div>


                <?php
                endwhile;

            endif;




}

add_shortcode('lorem', 'teatro_func');
```

Comment: I believe you'll need to do a WP Query before you can do a loop while inside a shortcode function. https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Then you'll need to adjust your loop to be like the one listed in the document linked above (Loop over the query instance, not the standard page loop)

Comment: there is **return** statement just after the `the_post();`.
Try removing that one and check if that works.

Answer (score -1):

Try Below code,

```
$args = array(
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'post_type'      => 'post'
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );

if( $query->have_posts() ):
   while( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>

    <div class="teatro-all">
      Your fields goes here.....  
    </div>  

<?php
   endwhile; 
else :
   endif;
```

Comment: shortcode should return the html. above solutions not work.

Comment: Working properly for me.

Comment: shortcode should return the html. it not work if we are using widget or somewhere.

Comment: May be your right but code is working in widget as well as in pages.